# How can ++ and : be used interchangably in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I read that the cons operator (:) and the ++ operator can be used interchangeably in Haskell strings. How can this be done? I'm not sure I completely understand what it means.

Edit: here's what I think it should be:

```
x:xs = [x]++xs
```

and

```
[]++list = list

(x:xs)++list = x:(xs++list)
```

Comment: Where did you read that?

Comment: in a practice lab assignment where you need to implement it

Comment: Please quote the paragraph (or whatever context is required for understanding the statement) that says so. That would be plain wrong, so you may have misunderstood something.

Comment: I have given an example of what it means, perhaps that helps?

Comment: Your edit is correct.  Those are the two conversions back and forth.

Answer (score 6):

`(:)` is a constructor for the list type. It's a special case of a rule that we can have infix constructors as long as they start with a colon:

```
Prelude> :info []
data [] a = [] | a : [a]    -- Defined in `GHC.Types'
```

`(++)` is a function trivially [implemented](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28%2B%2B%29) in terms of `(:)`:

```
Prelude> :info (++)
(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]   -- Defined in `GHC.Base'
infixr 5 ++
```

As you can see the types are different:

```
Prelude> :t (:)
(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]
Prelude> :t (++)
(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
```

Above I've used hoogle (and implementations linked in haddock docs) and GHCi with the `:t` and `:info` commands, and now you can too!

Answer (score 2):

```
x:xs = [x]++xs
```

and

```
[]++list = list

(x:xs)++list = x:(xs++list)
```